# JQuery Galleryview

Tags: jquery, galleryview

I have a web page with JQuery GalleryView plugin and for some reason thumbnail in the filmstrip is always faded even though its the actively selected record. Only initially when it binds for the first time, first image is clear but when I scroll through images film strip images just stays faded. My webpage is accessible at:

http://ssdev01.uis.kent.edu/VotingApplication/Main.aspx

once you are on the page please click on either "Homecoming King" or "Homecoming Queen" option for the plugin. Please help

Comment: When you say "blurred" do you mean "faded?"

Comment: yes. its not clear which one is active

Comment: If you open the browser's console you might notice that the browser isn't able to load `loading.gif` and `controls.png` due to HTTP 404 errors. That might be part of the problem.

Comment: problem still persist as those images were used for colorbox plugin. Thanks for pointing it out though :)

Comment: BTW you should change `transition_interval: 50000000` to `transition_interval: 0` if you don't want the gallery to automatically play.

Comment: Also, see my edit - I'm pretty sure I found the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>You're using GalleryView 3.0b3, released March 15, 2011, with jQuery 1.3.2, released February 19, 2009. The latest version of jQuery is 1.5.2, released March 31, 2011.</s>

**Update jQuery.**

---

### Edit

Looking through the Galleria source code, this is the bit that fades back out, unless `this` is the currently selected image:

```
.mouseout(function(){
    //Don't fade out current frame on mouseout
    if(!$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('current')){
        $(this).stop().animate({opacity:opts.frame_opacity},300);
    }
});
```

but in your page, `$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('current')` returns `false`. I think that you're not using *exactly* the right HTML structure that GalleryView expects, as in [this demo](http://spaceforaname.com/galleryview-3.0/galleria2.html). In your page, `$(this).parent().parent()` is a `<div>`, but based on that demo, GalleryView seems to expect it to be an `<li>`.

So, I see are two possible fixes:

- Use raw markup ("raw" as in, before GV modifies it) with structure that's **identical** to the HTML structure in the GV demo I linked, or
- (I'm less sure about this one) change line 595 of `jquery.galleryview-3.0.js` from

  ```
    if(!$(this).parent().parent().hasClass('current')){$(this).stop().animate({opacity:opts.frame_opacity},300);}
  ```

  to

  ```
    if(!$(this).closest('li').hasClass('current')){$(this).stop().animate({opacity:opts.frame_opacity},300);}
  ```

Comment: Did you change that on the live site, or a dev one? On the kent.edu page, I still see jQuery 1.3.2.

Comment: perfect changing line 595 in the js file did help :) I updated JQuery version on my local machine & it did not help so I did not publish it on the link above. Anyways, link provided above is on the dev server & not the live site ;) Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: Just in case you need the code of GalleryView 3.0 Beta3 and find the previous location of the script unaccessible, download it from here: [github.com/tadeck/galleryview](https://github.com/tadeck/galleryview/) (uploaded to GitHub before the original location went down).